# Project with high coverage sought

Tags: open-source, code-coverage, rtems

I was wondering if there is any project with high coverage requirement.
To be more precisely, I'm looking for:

- Open Source Project, I need to access to the code
- Any class of software, e.g., library, operating system, gui
- Data on the coverage achieved. Here coverage can be meant as statement coverage, branch, MC/DC
- Any language

I already have such an example. It is a free open source RTOS, [RTEMS](http://www.rtems.org/ftp/pub/rtems/people/joel/coverage/). Do you have any other examples?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Sqlite is renown for having high test coverage: http://www.sqlite.org/testing.html sadly not all the test cases are freely available.

Another list of Java programs and their test coverage is on http://www.testabilityexplorer.org/report .

Comment: This was closed as not constructive, try to avoid posting on closed questions. Especially if you answer is just links.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the sonar nemo instance you will find some libraries with high coverage:

http://nemo.sonarsource.org

e.g.:Commons Lang (apache commons lang): http://nemo.sonarsource.org/dashboard/index/269309?asc=false&sort=5

All projects there should be open source (look for the sources link).